# SQL how to get the running sum + the current value?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need some help for my case.
I have a table like this

```
   date     id  Value
01.01.2020  A   1
02.01.2020  A   1
03.01.2020  A   0
04.01.2020  A   2
05.01.2020  A   1
01.01.2020  B   0
02.01.2020  B   1
03.01.2020  B   3
04.01.2020  B   -1
05.01.2020  B   2
01.01.2020  C   1
02.01.2020  C   2
03.01.2020  C   1
04.01.2020  C   1
05.01.2020  C   2
```

what I would like to have a reulst is like this:
It is the running sum of the value in the past and plus the value of the current date.

```
    date    id  Value   Result
 01.01.2020  A   1        1    --> 1+0
 02.01.2020  A   1        2    --> 1+1
 03.01.2020  A   0        3    --> 0+2+1 --> value on the current date + sum of the value above
 04.01.2020  A   2        8    --> 2+3+2+1
 05.01.2020  A   1        15   --> 1+8+3+2+1
 01.01.2020  B   0        0    --> 0  new id, calculate restart
 02.01.2020  B   1        1    --> 1+0 
 03.01.2020  B   3        4    --> 3+1 
 04.01.2020  B   -1       4
 05.01.2020  B   2        11
 01.01.2020  C   1        1
 02.01.2020  C   2        3
 03.01.2020  C   1        5
 04.01.2020  C   1        10
 05.01.2020  C   2        21
```

For the running, it is not difficult to calculate,
something like:

```
 select t1.*,
 SUM(t1.value) over (PARTITION by t1.id order by t1.date) cum_sum
 from t1;
```

But I didn't figure it out, how to add the current value with the cum_sum  to get the final result.

any suggestions?

Comment: Your query appears to be correct.  What is the issue?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - OP doesn't want a simple cumulative sum, they're asking for a recursive cumulative sum.

Comment: What is the business case behind this problem? Where, in real life, do you need to compute such iterated cumulative sums? Unless this is from some kind of "academic challenge", I would strongly suspect that the problem hasn't been modeled correctly (meaning, not the "coding" part, but the "mathematics" part that comes before any kind of "code" is written).

Answer (score 3):

If you consider the sample data:

```
DATE | VALUE
---- | -----
D1   |     a
D2   |     b
D3   |     c
D4   |     d
D5   |     e
```

- At `D1`, you want `a`.
- At `D2`, you want `b` plus the `D1` result, which gives `a + b`.
- At `D3`, you want `c` plus the `D1` and `D2` results, which gives `(a) + (a + b) + (c) = 2a + b + c`.
- At `D4`, you want `d` plus the `D1`, `D2` and `D3` results, which gives `(a) + (a + b) + (2a + b + c) + (d) = 4a + 2b + c + d`.
- At `D5`, you want `e` plus the `D1`, `D2`, `D3` and `D4` results, which gives `(a) + (a + b) + (2a + b + c) + (4a + 2b + c + d) + (e) = 8a + 4b + 2c + d + e`.

From this, you can see that the multipliers on the terms are increasing in powers of two. Or that you double the previous accumulated result, subtract the previous value and add the current value.

---

You can join the table to itself and `SUM` the previous values each multiplied by the 2 raised to the power of the number of days difference - 1:

```sql
SELECT t1."date",
       t1.id,
       MAX( t1.value ) AS value,
       SUM( POWER( 2, GREATEST( t1."date" - t1a."date" - 1, 0 ) ) *  t1a.value )
         AS result
FROM   t1
       INNER JOIN t1 t1a
       ON ( t1a."date" <= t1."date" AND t1a.id = t1.id )
GROUP BY t1."date", t1.id
ORDER BY id, "date"
```

*(Note: `DATE` is a keyword in Oracle and if you want to use it as a column identifier then you will need to surround it in double-quotes and always use the same case letters.)*

However, a simpler method is to use the `MODEL` clause:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   t1
MODEL
  PARTITION BY (id)
  DIMENSION BY ("date")
  MEASURES ( value, 0 AS result)
  RULES (
    result["date"] = COALESCE( 2 * result[cv("date")-1] - value[cv("date")-1], 0 )
                     + value[cv("date")]
  )
ORDER BY id, "date"
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1 ( "date", id, Value ) AS
SELECT DATE '2020-01-01', 'A', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-02', 'A', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-03', 'A', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-04', 'A', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-05', 'A', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-01', 'B', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-02', 'B', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-03', 'B', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-04', 'B', -1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-05', 'B', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-01', 'C', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-02', 'C', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-03', 'C', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-04', 'C', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-05', 'C', 2 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> ```
> date                | ID | VALUE | RESULT
> :------------------ | :- | ----: | -----:
> 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | A  |     1 |      1
> 2020-01-02 00:00:00 | A  |     1 |      2
> 2020-01-03 00:00:00 | A  |     0 |      3
> 2020-01-04 00:00:00 | A  |     2 |      8
> 2020-01-05 00:00:00 | A  |     1 |     15
> 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | B  |     0 |      0
> 2020-01-02 00:00:00 | B  |     1 |      1
> 2020-01-03 00:00:00 | B  |     3 |      4
> 2020-01-04 00:00:00 | B  |    -1 |      4
> 2020-01-05 00:00:00 | B  |     2 |     11
> 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | C  |     1 |      1
> 2020-01-02 00:00:00 | C  |     2 |      3
> 2020-01-03 00:00:00 | C  |     1 |      5
> 2020-01-04 00:00:00 | C  |     1 |     10
> 2020-01-05 00:00:00 | C  |     2 |     21
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a2b3c3521648ffe68e4c016a708afe02)*

Answer (score 2):

I freely admit that this is based on MTOs understanding of the problem.  However, a more efficient way to implement the logic just uses window functions and arithmetic, rather than a self-join:

```
select t1.*, sum(power(2, -seqnum) * value) over (partition by id order by dte) as x1, 
       (value +
        coalesce(sum(power(2, -seqnum) * value) over (partition by id order by dte range between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 0) /
        power(2, 1-seqnum) 
       ) as result
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by dte) as seqnum
      from t1
     ) t1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6e5fd4fe54e8355d1cc7776a110a2151) is a db<>fiddle.